# How can I tell if java was installed by default on ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, java

I don't recall installing java on my Ubuntu 20.4 system, so I'm asking **is there a way to know if it came pre-installed on the OS distribution**.  I usually, only expect the JRE to be installed not the JDK.

A search for the answer said that Ubuntu 20.04 includes Open JDK 11.  But I seem to have Java JDK 8 installed.

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

So I'm guessing that I installed it and just forgot that I did the install.

Alternatively, **is there a way to know if java was installed using apt, ufw, yum, rpm or another package manager, or manually via `cd /opt; tar xzf pkg.tgz`**.

### What I've tried

Searching for an answer led me to this:

#### #1 ------------------------------------------------------------

- https://linuxconfig.org/list-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux - Found when searching `list of packages installed on ubuntu 20.04`.  It says I could run
  `apt list --installed | egrep -i 'jdk|java'`.  Output is shown below

```
apt list --installed | egrep -i 'jdk|java'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

ca-certificates-java/focal,focal,now 20190405ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.30.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
java-common/focal,focal,now 0.72 all [installed,automatic]
javascript-common/focal,focal,now 11 all [installed,automatic]
libatk-wrapper-java-jni/focal,now 0.37.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libatk-wrapper-java/focal,focal,now 0.37.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.30.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libjuh-java/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libjurt-java/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libridl-java/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libunoloader-java/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jdk-headless/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jdk/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-8-jre-headless/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jre/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed]
```

So I'm seeing `[installed,automatic]` and wondering if that is telling my that it was pre-installed (or came with the OS install).

#### #2 ------------------------------------------------------------

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04, which told me that by default Open JDK 11 is installed which doesn't seem to be the case (but it might be somewhere that I haven't looked).

On some other Linux systems I've worked on they have used the `alternatives` command.  See https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command or https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives.

Below is a block quote from the linux.die.net website which is provided just in case the link stops working at some time in the future.

> alternatives creates, removes, maintains and displays information about the symbolic links comprising the alternatives system. The alternatives system is a reimplementation of the Debian alternatives system. It was rewritten primarily to remove the dependence on perl; it is intended to be a drop in replacement for Debian's update-dependencies script. This man page is a slightly modified version of the man page from the Debian project.

#### #3 ------------------------------------------------------------

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-java-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux/ - which explains how to install Java on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Try examining contents of file `/var/log/dpkg.log` ?  And to see if the java package files have changed (e.g. via tarball) since it was first installed, try `debsums <pkgname>`

Comment: @steve, Not much in `dpkg.log` (only 30 lines or so) and nothing with Java or JDK appearing  and `debsums` was not installed.

Comment: (@steve+) also look at archived files `dpkg.log.{1,2,...}{,.gz}` `[automatic]` means a package was installed because something else depends on it -- notice `openjdk-8-{jre,jdk}-headless` and `java-common` are 'automatic' but `openjdk-8-{jre,jdk}` are not: the latter were explicitly installed and forced the installation of the `-headless` parts.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 come with openjdk 11 preinstalled. You have installed openjdk 8 manually using `apt` (or installation script) because the build number `1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08` indicate that the package belongs to Ubuntu repositories.